# Why does enthalpy change differ in a chemical reaction because of temperature?

Tags: physical-chemistry, enthalpy

If enthalpy is a state function, shouldn't the change in enthalpy be the same between a given initial and final state, regardless of how the change took place? Kirchoff's equation describes this variation as
$$\Delta H_{T_2} = \Delta H_{T_1} + \Delta C_p (T_2 - T_1).$$
I'm guessing that this change in enthalpy change is only because of the variation in $C_p$, but I'm not too sure about it. Am I completely wrong about this?

Comment: The equation does look wrong to me. Shouldn't it be $$H(T_2) = H(T_1) + C_p(T_2 - T_1)?$$ Enthalpy is a state function.

Comment: Yes, enthalpy is a state function, and the rest is also true. Now what is your question?

Comment: You are right there. IF the total heat capacities of reagents and products  were by chance equal, the reaction enthalpy would be temperature independent. 
But as these total heat capacities are generally different, the reaction enthalpy is temperature dependent. As the net heat for changing temperature of reactants and changing it back for products is nonzero.

Comment: @OneEyedMushroom Yes, the change in enthalpy is independent of path, depending only on the initial and final states. But ΔH_T2 is going to be different from ΔH_T1. That's because the initial and final states for a reaction at T1 are different from a reaction at T2.  Specifically, ΔH_T1 is the change in enthlapy in going from reactants at T1 to products at T1.  ΔH_T2 is the change in enthalpy is going from reactants at T2 to products at T2.  And your eqn is essentially correct, except it makes the common simplifying assuption that the diff. in Cp between reactants and products is T-independent.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン  The equation is OK,  because it's referring to the temperature-dependence of ΔH for a reaction, which in turn depends on the difference in heat capacities between the reactants and products (ΔCp).  Its one simpifying assumption is that it assumes ΔCp is T-independent.

Comment: If you're looking at the change at two different temperatures, then the initial states and final states are different?

Comment: @theorist now that you say it... Thanks for giving it a more thorough look.

Comment: @theorist but why DeltaCp it is thought as a difference? It could change differently along the path/Tactual... I don't understand this.

Comment: @Alchimista  Sorry, I can't make sense of your question.   Can you please rewrite it in a clear and precise manner so I can understand just what you are asking?

Comment: @theorist I don't understand why Cp is considered at the initial and final stages only. Shouldn't be its variation along the reaction important? Or its T dependance?

Comment: @Alchimista You'd need to look at a derivation of the eqn. to understand more fully, but Kirchoff's eqn does do that, i.e., it is obtained by integrating delta_Cp from T1 to T2 (the equations you see here are obtained by assuming delta_Cp is T-independent, so the delta_Cp can be taken out of the integral).

Comment: @Alchimista  I think it would help looking at my answers here:  https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/142033/calculating-change-in-state-function-following-different-paths/142083#142083  and here:  https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/61749/enthalpy-of-a-reaction-changes-with-temperature-does-this-mean-bond-strengths-c/132470#132470

Comment: Temperature is one of the state variables. If you change the temperature, you have a different state.

Answer (score 4):

From Hess' law, the heat of reaction at temperatures $T_1$ and $T_2$ are related by $$\Delta H_{T_1}=C_{p,\mathrm r}(T_2-T_1)+\Delta H_{T_2}+C_{p,\mathrm p}(T_1-T_2),$$where $C_{p,\mathrm r}$ is the heat capacity of a stoichiometric molar mixture of reactants and $C_{p,\mathrm p}$ is the heat capacity of a stoichiometric molar mixture of products.